# Updating approval status at end of workflow

Tags: workflow, approval-process

I have created a custom approval workflow using Sharepoint Designer 2010. The workflow starts when a document is selected for publish a major version and routes it to different approvers depending on what the document is. The workflow seems to be working OK, but at the end of the workflow the approval status is not updated. I tried adding the "set field in current item" action at the end of the workflow, but approval status is not in the drop down menu.

I can see that the approval workflow that comes with Sharepoint has an option to "Update the approval status after the workflow is completed" and I was tried creating a workflow using this to see what this does to the workflow process in sharepoint designer, but after creating a workflow in the Sharepoint website, I cannot see the workflow in sharepoint designer (I can see the workflows I have created from scratch under "List workflows" and the "Globally reusable workflows" but not the one I have just created.

Can anyone tell me either how to look at the design of the new workflow I created through sharepoint website, or how to update the approval status in a custom workflow?

By the way, I have I have Full control permissions (I am part of the sandbox owner group)

Your help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Kind regards,

New sharepoint user!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a "Set Content Approval Status" action available in SharePoint Designer 2010